# Custom Branding for application

Tags: cumulocity

I am having trouble with branding the application in cumulocity.
I tried to test branding by cloning the cockpit app to use our Branding.
If i see in the manage application window i am not able to customize the branding/logo. I don't see the option to customize the branding Although i removed the cumulocity branding plugin from the app now I only see the name of my application as the logo. 
In the plugins window i saw only cumulocity branding, nothing for custom branding. Can you please correct me if i missed something?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I would  do it. Clone or download the cumulocity-ui-plugin-examples from the cumulocity  [repository](https://bitbucket.org/m2m/cumulocity-ui-plugin-examples/downloads/) then:

1. Go to plugins folder
2. Find myBranding folder
3. Now go to the img folder and changes the logo-main.svg and logo.svg for your desire logos. Also, you can check the colors.less file in the variables folder and change the colors of your application UI.
4. Now go to the main folder (where you download the repository) and run `c8y deploy:plugin myBranding`. This command create a .zip file of the plugin.
5. Next, go the administration app in Cumulocity , find the app your cloned and click on edit, then go to the plugins tab. There you can find the list of the plugins that your app is using.
6. Find the Branding: Cumulocity plugin and click on remove like [image].
7. Next, in the same menu, click on add plugin.
8. Look on your computer for the .zip file you create on the 4 step and load it.
9. Click on save.
10. Open your app.

    Note: If you haven't installed the c8y tool and assuming you have installed nodejs , just run  `npm i cumulocity-tools -g` to get the tool. See [this great documentation](http://cumulocity.com/guides/web/introduction/) for more info.

You can find a documentation related to this in: [branding guide](http://cumulocity.com/guides/web/branding-plugin/).

Hope this helps!